# Validation jQuery, remote is redirecting wrong in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

In application.js ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#new_academic_formation").validate({
debug: true,
rules: {
      "academic_formation[id]": {
      required: true,  
      minlength: 3, 
      remote:  "/academic_formations/check_id"
      }
}     
});
});
```

In my academic_formations_controller.rb

```
def check_id
    @academic_formation = AcademicFormation.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => !@academic_formation }
    end
end
```

And finally in file routes.rb

```
resources :academic_formations
match "/academic_formations/check_id" => 'academic_formations#check_id'
```

The problem is that instead of calling the action check_id rails is calling the action show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to move `match "/academic_formations/check_id" => 'academic_formations#check_id'` before `resources :academic_formations`.

This is straight from the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

"Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a `resources :photos` above a `get 'photos/poll'` the show action’s route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first."

OR

Since yours is a resourceful route, you may add a route as, if it applies to a collection(you can read more about that in the docs linked above) and if it's a `get` method as :

```
resources :academic_formations do
  collection do
    get 'check_id'
  end
end
```